# How to call external web service using PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am using a service to send sms using php by redirecting to service page 
(e.g http://example.com?receiver=38383&msg=test)

If I want to send a message to one phone number I can redirect to this page, but I want to send a lot of message using for loop.
I can't redirect to the page because it will stop the PHP script.
I tried cURL but I don't have any results.
Can you help me?

This is the code of cURL:

```
$path = "http://example.com?receiver=38383&msg=test";
$opts = array(CURLOPT_URL => $path,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
           CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $return;
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using.

Comment: Do you need to actually _redirect_ the application's UI to the service URL?  Or can you hit the service URL in the back-end code in an automated manner?  If the latter, doing it in a loop should be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function sendSMS($receiver, $message) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com?receiver" . $receiver . "&msg=" . $message);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}

echo sendSMS (38383, "test");
```

Comment: It display "The page cannot be displayed" and sms does not send, I test the url only (in browser) its correct